# Prove the period of the transformed function

Tags: functions

I have the following statement to prove:

> Prove that if $f:X \to Y$ with $x \in X$ have a period $T$, therefore $f(Ax)$ have a period $\frac{T}{A}$

My development was:

If $f$ have a period $T$ holds that $f(x+T) = f(x)$

I need to prove that $f(Ax+\frac{T}{A})=f(Ax)$.

I don't know how to do it, since I don't know how I can "operate" with the function arguments.

Comment: Be careful what you write!  You want the function $x\mapsto f(Ax)$, so where does $x+\frac{T}{A}$ get mapped to under this?

Answer (score 1):

You have $f(x+T) = f(x)$, and you want to show that for $g(x) = f(Ax)$, you have $g\left(x+\dfrac{T}{A}\right) = g(x)$.

Note that $g\left(x+\dfrac{T}{A}\right) = f\left(A\left(x+\dfrac{T}{A}\right)\right) \neq f\left(Ax+\dfrac{T}{A}\right)  $.